# How can I make ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP optional?

Tags: mysql

When I append,

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I know the column will be updated when the row is updated.

Is there any way to make the clause optional?

I mean a way to update the column only when client didn't send the column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use trigger logic:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
BEFORE UPDATE
ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.datetimefield = COALESCE(NEW.datetimefield, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Do not forget to remove ON UPDATE attribute from field definition.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to handle your requirement would be to always include the timestamp column in question in the update, but wrap it in `COALESCE` and use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default value, e.g.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET
    col1 = <some value>,
    co2l = <some other value>,
    ts_col = COALESCE(?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
WHERE ...
```

To the `?` placeholder, you would either bind a value, should you want to explicitly update it, or just bind `NULL` if you don't want to update it.  The `NULL` value would be replaced with the current timestamp.